# Two strings are not the same but actually they are in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-comparison

I have implemented bfs in python in a simple way.
First I create a Graph class which has an inner class Node, this node contains its id, a list of neighbors and a boolean to decide if it has been visited or not

The Graphic class only contains the bfs method where I am saving the route in a string.

The method works, but when comparing the final result with the expected result, I get that they are not the same

What is this about? if they are both strings, even at the end of the bfs I do str()

Here my code, I have python 3.8.7

```
    def bfs(self):
        """Algoritmo BFS.
        
        Regresa:
        Una cadena de enteros de la forma '0,3,8,10,2' que indica el orden en 
        el que su algoritmo recorrió la gráfica.
        NOTA: deben usar el nodo en self.nodes[0] como raíz de sus recorridos.
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        Return:
        A string of integers of the form '0,3,8,10,2' indicating the order in 
        which your algorithm traversed the graph.
        NOTE: You must use the node in self.nodes[0] as the root of your traversals.
        """
        self.nodos[0].visit = True
        cola = [self.nodos[0]]
        recorrido = '' #para ir guardando el recorrido | We save the path in a str
        while (cola != []):
            elem = cola.pop(0)
            recorrido+=str(elem.id)+','
            
            for v in elem.vecinos:
                nodo = self.nodos[v]
                if nodo.visit is False:  #we obtain the id of the node to consult it in the list of the node
                    cola.append(nodo)
                    nodo.visit = True

        return str(recorrido[:-1])#to remove the last comma


# ------------------ MAIN --------------------------
def prueba_grafica(g, res_esperado):
    """Método auxiliar para facilitar las pruebas de su BFS."""
    print('Probando ' + str(g))
    print(f'BFS_ESPERADO : {g.bfs()}\nBFS_RESULTADO: {res_esperado}')
    if g.bfs() == res_esperado:
        print('Resultado correcto!')
    else:
        print('Resultado incorrecto :(') #I obatain this when the result of the bfs is 0,1,2,3,4, why?


adyacencias = [[1, 2], [0, 3, 4], [0], [1, 4], [1, 3]]
resultado_esperado = '0,1,2,3,4'
g = Grafica(adyacencias, 'A')
prueba_grafica(g, resultado_esperado)
```

Shell:

```
BFS_ESPERADO : 0,1,2,3,4
BFS_RESULTADO: 0,1,2,3,4
Resultado incorrecto :(
```

Incorrect result, why?

Thanks!

Comment: print them both as bytes and see what the difference is

Comment: You are calling `g.bfs()` twice - once to print it out before the comparison and once as part of the comparison.  Are you sure the second call of `g.bfs()` does not return a different result (e.g. because node.visit has been changed and it seems not to be reset on the subsequent call of the function)? Perhaps comment out the print statement and see if it works.

Comment: As noted, your call to `g.bfs()` has side-effects. This is probably not a good way to do it to begin with, you don't ac tually *need* to have a `visit` attribute, use a `set` of nodes to keep track of visited nodes! By default, user-defined objects hash by identity, so this should just work

Comment: But what does this have to do with the chain? That is, what I compare are the chains 0,1,2,3,4 but not Nodes, the visit or anything else